# Regex to ensure every number in range is matched once

Tags: regex, excel, vba

I'm trying to match tokens using regex. So far I have

```
\{[0-2]\}
```

Which looks for all instances of `{0}`, `{1}` and `{2}` in a string. I want to ensure each of these appears at least once in a given string. I can just count the results of the regex and verify each, but I wonder if there's a way to do it in regex directly?

Example

```
"{0}{1}{2}" - True
"{1}{0}{2}" - True (rearrangement)
"{1}{0}{2}{2}" - True (repetition fine)
"foo{1}bar{0}blah{2}" - True
"foo{2}bar{0}blah{2}" - False (no {1})
"foo{2}bar{0}blah{12}" - False (no {1})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use look-ahead conditions for this:

```
(?=.*\{0\})(?=.*\{1\})(?=.*\{2\})
```

The first `(?=.*\{0\})` condition will try to match {0} somewhere in your string, *without consuming the string*, then `(?=.*\{1\})` will try to match {1} *starting again from the beginning of the string*, etc.

Note: the `.*` in the first look-ahead condition is not strictly necessary since you're not necessarily matching from the beginning of the string, but I included it for symmetry reasons...

Answer (score 1):

I would do it by checking separately if every token is present:

```
\{1\}
\{2\}
\{3\}
```

and then composing it in a conjunction (`AND`).

Answer (score 1):

I fear RegExps are not a good fit for your use-case as they will be less maintainable and slower than a more direct approach like:

```
Function AllInStr(str As String, tokens() As String) As Boolean
    AllInStr = True
    Dim token As Variant
    For Each token In tokens
        AllInStr = AllInStr And InStr(str, token) <> 0
        If Not AllInStr Then Exit Function
    Next
End Function
```

Validated by this test-case:

```
Sub test()
    Dim tokens() As String
    tokens = Split("{0} {1} {2}")

    Debug.Assert AllInStr("{0}{1}{2}", tokens)
    Debug.Assert AllInStr("{1}{0}{2}", tokens)
    Debug.Assert AllInStr("{1}{0}{2}{2}", tokens)
    Debug.Assert AllInStr("foo{1}bar{0}blah{2}", tokens)
    Debug.Assert Not AllInStr("foo{2}bar{0}blah{2}", tokens)
    Debug.Assert Not AllInStr("foo{2}bar{0}blah{12}", tokens)
End Sub
```

Comment: Yeah, that might be a shout, a quick test gives this:
`Regex: 90.566E-03 s` ,`Standard: 1.997E-03 s`, i.e the regex is ~2 orders of magnitude slower over the test cases

Comment: Thanks for the benchmark, always good to have the numbers. :)